# how to pass data to subview controller in ios app from the calling method didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, didselectrowatindexpath

Could somebody explain me what i'm doing wrong in the code below?
I try to pass data from the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method but in the **SizeViewController** productKey has still  value of null

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

                [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
                SizeViewController *sizeViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SizeView"];
                sizeViewController.title = [self.choosedProducts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                sizeViewController.productKey  = [self.choosedProductsIds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                [[self navigationController]pushViewController:sizeViewController animated:YES];
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can u try to get a reference to the storyboard instead of using the self.storyboard property? It is just a guess.

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
```

Also, can u verify in your solution that sizeViewController is not nil?

Comment: Your answer doesn't change anything. I do not know why but the title working properly displaying the name in the child window instead of productKey which has null value all the time. Maybe I made some mistakes in the subview class?

Comment: Can u check if the item [self.choosedProductsIds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; is nil?

Comment: Thank you very much. I guess I have to take a day off from programming, because I make a stupid mistakes like this one :( Good job

Comment: No worries, have a nice rest!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to load a view controller from storyboard,So it should be initialised as

```
SizeViewController* detailViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SizeViewController storyboard identifier"];
```

Comment: I change my code but now the subview doesnt load and I have log info: Application tried to push a nil view controller on target <UINavigationController: 0x17e5e910>.